# phpMyAdmin Error #1064 using MYSQL40 compatability mode

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I got an error #1064 when trying to upload my sql file to phpMyAdmin. The database is called "dodgingdeath wordpresspage".

The error says:

"#1064 - You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near "wordpresspage" at line 1"

Here's the first part of my sql file, any ideas where the syntax-error could be?
Line 1 is obviously only comment. I also don't see any syntax error near "wordpresspage"

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Erstellungszeit: 11. Feb 2017 um 17:49
-- Server Version: 5.6.12-log
-- PHP-Version: 5.4.12

SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `dodgingdeath wordpresspage`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dodgingdeath wordpresspage` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE dodgingdeath wordpresspage;
```

Further info: 
- I used phpMyAdmin v5.4.12 on the local host (WampServer) and v5.4.38 on the webserver. Could this be a problem? 
- As I got an error #1273 earlier, I uploaded the files using sql compatability mode "MYSQL40", which is how I ended up with error #1064....

Answer (score 0):

As your db name has spaces, use double quotes in USE, so:

```
USE "dodgingdeath wordpresspage";
```

Comment: you can also use backticks (`) or single quotes (') to wrap the dbName. Another solution is to escape the space character, so : USE dodgingdeath\ wordpresspage;

Comment: I tried both options, I still get another #1064 error eitherway. 

Error occures near ''  dodgingdeath\wordpress' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci' " ...............Here's the Code.... 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  'dodgingdeath\wordpress' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

Comment: Alright backticks (`) and escaping space character solved the problem :) Thank you so much!! 
so i wrote "  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dd` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE dd;   "